# How to analyze responses to a survey involving rating 5 factors on a scale of 1-100?

Tags: ranking

I am conducting a survey where I ask respondents to rate five factors on a scale from 1 to 100 on how much the factor affects an individual's perception of the value of a particular product.

How can I determine whether the valuation of the  product is standard or not standard across respondents?

Comment: Could you tell us what it means for a valuation to be "standard ... across respondents"?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is not very clear. Do you want to analyze interindividual variability? Do you expect that the answers are intercorrelated among the five items?

- If you want to describe the interindividual variability of responses, it is sufficient for you, for each item, to examine the distribution of responses (histogram + mean + deviation). That gives you a central tendency and the extent to which responses vary in the sample around this central tendency. In addition, if you have any assumptions about the reasons for differences between individuals, you can test them by analysis such as a regression.
- If you are interested in the structure of the responses of the subjects (and you have a sample large enough), and you want to validate your measure, you can perform a factor analysis or simply a reliability analysis (alpha of Cronbach). This allow you to check if the five items measure the same thing or not across participants.

But as it stands, it is difficult to help you without more fully understanding your goal.

Answer (score 0):

As @maxTC discusses, we need to know more about the study to help you analyze it.

I can tell you, however, that I'm skeptical of the meaning of a 100-point scale. A scale of 1 to 100 will allow for much precision, but it's harder to figure out what other than the perception of the product determines the rating people give. For example, maybe people round their numbers in unexpected ways. Or if you're using a visual analog scale, maybe the size of their hands affects the rating. Also if you don't validate the scale in some way (that is, relate it to some gold standard), it is difficult to explain what a small difference (like 50 versus 45) means.

If you validate it somehow, what I just said is less important.

I advise that you choose a scale whose results can convincingly be related to the unobserved variable of interest, perception of value. It also helps if you choose a scale that can be easily and convincingly transformed to [interval data rather than ordinal data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_measurement). William Moroney's [adverb intensifiers](http://academic.udayton.edu/williammoroney/adverb_intensifiers_for_use_in_r.htm) list might help with that.

Comment: I wonder about both parts of this reply.  First, when the responses vary, more precision *helps:* without that precision, you have less power to observe (and quantify) the variation!  (Tukey's collected works contain several analyses of this.)  Second, the choice of scale *never* affects how you can analyze the data (in any situation) unless you so constrain your analytical tools that you're unwilling to re-express the values (which would be foolish: maybe that's the point you're trying to make).

Comment: Hmm I suppose I could have used weaker language, explained myself more and been less cynical regarding the first part. As for the second part, that is the point I'm trying to make.